# How to stop an audio player when closing a readmore/close panel.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to stop the audio track from playing when I close the expanded panel it is shown in. I've looked extensively on the internet for code to do this and not finding anything. Here is the sample page with a two track sample. http://sageturtledesign.com/garrettmartin/readmore.html
I'm using a simple expandable script. 
Here's what's in the head tag for audio player and for read/more script:

```
 <script src="audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    var as = audiojs.createAll();
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

// The height of the content block when it's not expanded
var adjustheight = 15;
// The "more" link text
var moreText = "+  Listen & Lyrics";
// The "less" link text
var lessText = "- Close";

// Sets the .more-block div to the specified height and hides any content that overflows
$(".more-less .more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
// The section added to the bottom of the "more-less" div
$(".more-less").append('<a href="#" class="adjust"></a>');


$("a.adjust").text(moreText);

$(".adjust").toggle(function() {
        $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
        // Hide the [...] when expanded
        $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'none');
        $(this).text(lessText);
    }, function() {
        $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'block');
        $(this).text(moreText);
});
});

</script>
```

Here's the html for it:

This belongs to you

```
    <div class="more-block">
       <p>Words &amp; Music by Jan Garrett, JD Martin, &amp; Ester Nicholson</p>
       <p><audio src="audio/SongStudio/IBelieveThisBelongsToYou_S.mp3" preload="auto" /></p>
    <div><p>I once heard a powerful story....About a man who stood in his truth <br />
      With such conviction in who he was that he would not be moved<br />
      Someone stepped out of a crowd and said, “Are you Martin Luther King?”<br />
      He said “Yes I am,” and the well-dressed man.....spit on him<br />
      Then King took out his handkerchief and wiped the hate from his suit<br />
      He gave it back to the man and said, “I believe this belongs to you.”</p>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you label the audio players with either a class or ID (so you can select the specific one), then you don't have to pause all audio players on the page:

```
$('.adjust').click(function(){        //if you click 'Close'
  $('audio').each(function(){       //select every audio element on the page
    this.pause();                   //pause audio players [0] to [n]
  });
});
```

If your first audio has an attribute

```
'class="firstAudioPlayerClass"'
```

Then, if you want to pause that one, you can do:

```
$('.firstAudioPlayerClass').each(function(){
  this.pause()
});
```

---

Yea dude you have to either give each audio it's own ID, or use parent() closest() stuff like that to select the exact player you want (since you have 2 players..)

```
$('.play-pause .pause').trigger('click')
```

will also work also, but this will trigger both of them

Comment: I added this to the head tag:<script type="text/javascript">

$('.adjust').click(function(){        //if you click 'Close'
  $('audio').each(function(){       //select every audio element on the page
    this.pause();                   //pause audio players [0] to [n]
  });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.firstAudioPlayerClass').each(function(){
  this.pause()
});
</script> and to the player: <audio src="audio/SongStudio/IBelieveThisBelongsToYou_S.mp3" preload="auto" class="firstAudioPlayerClass" />                                                           Not working ???

Comment: I'll try to look at it later today, but I tried it in the chrome console and it worked okay

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if you need anything more from me. I've tried it in IE, Safai, Chrome - not working for me.